# how to split columns by certain category?

Tags: r

My data look like this:

```
  dd gg site
  5  10 A
  7  8  A
  5  6  B 
  7  9  B
```

I want to split the column of `site` according to `A and B`.desired output  is:

```
    dd gg site  gg_B
    5  10 A     6
    7  8  A     9
```

Comment: given the amount of confusion expressed in the answers perhaps you could edit your question a bit for clarity ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request seems strange in the way A values for site are treated differently than the B values.

Using this data:

```
xx = structure(list(dd = c(5L, 7L, 5L, 7L), gg = c(10L, 8L, 6L, 9L
), site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("dd", 
"gg", "site"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

We can "spread" the columns from long to wide format using `tidyr::spread`. but this eliminates the site column and treats A and B values of it the same:

```
library(tidyr)
(xx = spread(xx, key = site, value = gg))
#   dd  A B
# 1  5 10 6
# 2  7  8 9
```

Adding the `gg_` prefix to the names:

```
names(xx)[2:3] = paste("gg", names(xx[2:3]), sep = "_")
xx
#   dd gg_A gg_B
# 1  5   10    6
# 2  7    8    9
```

I would prefer data in the above format. If you want to exactly match your desired output, adding `xx$site = "A"` and renaming the existing columns is easy enough.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to split by site and then merge by the `dd` column. You can do this with `split` and `merge`:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="dd"), split(dat, dat$site))
#   dd gg.x site.x gg.y site.y
# 1  5   10      A    6      B
# 2  7    8      A    9      B
```

By using `Reduce`, this code should work even if you had more than two sites. I have performed an inner join, meaning I will only keep a row for a given value of `dd` if it is reported for all sites. If you wanted to instead keep a row for a given value of `dd` if it is used by 1 or more sites, you could use:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="dd", all=TRUE), split(dat, dat$site))
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you'd be happy with

```
library("reshape2")
dcast(dat,dd~site,value.var="gg")
##   dd  A B
## 1  5 10 6
## 2  7  8 9
```

?  (This is essentially the same as the `tidyr::spread()` answer suggested by others.)

Answer (score 3):

If the columns are always in the right order you simply cbind them:

```
l <- split(dat, dat$site)
l$B <- l$B$gg
cbind(l$A, l$B, deparse.level = 0)
```

Result:

```
  dd gg site l$B
1  5 10    A   6
2  7  8    A   9
```

Data:

```
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "  dd gg site
  5  10 A
                  7  8  A
                  5  6  B 
                  7  9  B ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tidyr` to turn the subset of your data that has the site you want in column in wide format and then use `dplyr::inner_join` to merge it with the subset of the data having the other sites.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  filter(site == "B") %>%
  spread(key = site, value = gg) %>%
  inner_join(filter(df, site != "B"))
## Joining by: "dd"
##   dd B gg site
## 1  5 6 10    A
## 2  7 9  8    A
```